# Git squash commits with same commit message

Tags: git, git-squash

Is there a simple Git command to squash all commits with the same commit message to one commit in a new branch?

A simple command seems to me:

```
git merge --squash BRANCH_WITH_SAME_COMMIT_MESSAGES
```

The problem is that I created that branch from the `develop` branch. All our done tickets gets merged into `develop`. So during working on `BRANCH_WITH_SAME_COMMIT_MESSAGES` our workflow is to merge the `develop` into `BRANCH_WITH_SAME_COMMIT_MESSAGES` if a done ticket gets merged into `develop`.

The problem is that also all the other stuff  from `develop` gets squashed, but I only want the commits squashed, that have the same commit message.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). You can selectively squash together commits in a branch using the [*Interactive Mode*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode).

To do this automatically by commit message you can use [`--autosquash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash). But for this the commits you want to squash/fixup must beginn with "`squash! <original message subject>`" / "`fixup! <original message subject>`".
You can create such commit messages using [`git commit --squash <original commit>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---squashltcommitgt) (or [`--fixup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---fixupltcommitgt)).

**However** as I read your question what you're *actually* want to do is remove duplicate commits, since the commits with the same message in your branches also contain the *same changes*?

In that case you should also use `git rebase` on your feature branch:

```sh
git rebase develop
```

This will *rebase* your branch with all commits that are not yet in `develop` onto of that effectively removing all duplicate commits and merges.

Comment: It is only one branch with that commits. I used the same commit message as a marker so that I can later squash them.

Comment: If you already use the same commit message explicitly just prefix it with `squash! ` / `fixup! ` and use `git rebase --autosquash` then.

Comment: What do you mean by "just prefix it..."? Do I have to change all the commit messages afterwards?

Comment: You could edit all existing commit messages - e.g. with [`git rebase -i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode) - and then apply the above approach. But my recommendation was meant for _future_ commit first of all.

Comment: For an existing branch probably not. Still your best bet on this is to use `git rebase -i` which gives you a plain text file where you can reorder and squash/fixup commits. If there are too many commits to do this manually you may still find a way to order them programmatically with a small script or something.